# How to change default font to Rockwell?

Tags: fonts

Im using latex to automate some report generation. We use the font Rockwell as a default font. Im not used to latex and I found many different ways of changing the default font but many of them seemed very strange and none of it worked for me! So what is a simple way to change the font and can I include a font like Rockwell without any problems or do I need to import not that standard fonts in a special way?

Comment: I don't think that support files for (pdf)latex exists. So I would suggest: Use xelatex and `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Rockwell}` (or whatever is the internal name of the font).

Comment: Thank you! I tried it but it still cannt find the Font-File. Where should I put the files so its recognised by xelatex? Error =>  `! I can't find file \`Rockwell'.`

Comment: Install the font (hopefully you have an open type font) in your system, e.g. for windows in C:\fonts.

Comment: I presume the font is installed on your System (by the way, which one? Windows?) If you have a quite new Distribution and are able to run XeTeX, then the command 

`\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Ligatures={Common}]{Rockwell}`

should work. Edit: Sorry, my solution is quite similar to the one Ulrike already posted, though mine does change the roman font only.

Comment: Im using Debian as a System and font is installed.

Comment: You should start to offer a bit more informations. Font format, font name, tex system, minimal example, log-file ...

Comment: Run `fc-list | grep Rockwell` or otherwise examine the `fc-list` output. If your font is installed properly, you will see the name by which you can select it with `fontspec`. If your font is not listed, place it in `~/.fonts` (create the directory if needed) and run `fc-cache`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as described in comments, is to determine the correct font name for use with `fontspec`.

### Mini-Howto on selecting fonts with fontconfig

XeTeX relies on OS-specific libraries to load fonts. In case of Linux it is the [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig) library. It's quite easy for basic use.

- If the font is already installed in the system (and many will be), it can be selected simply by its name. You can find out the precise name to use by issuing `fc-list` and examining the output (perhaps with the help of `grep`).
- If the font is not listed, it can be installed manually. Fonts can be installed system-wise or user-wise. I recommend the second way, because it does not require additional privileges and won't pollute the system directories. To install a font, simply place it in the `.fonts` directory in your home directory. You may need to create the directory if it doesn't exist, and you may need to enable display of hidden files to see this directory in your file manager. Once the font has been placed in the directory, run `fc-cache` to regenerate the font cache, then try the first step again.