# Proxima Nova as default font?

Tags: fonts, typography

I am writing a resume in Latex, and am still a beginner and want to use Proxima Nova as the default font. How do I use it?

Comment: If you have the fonts in OpenType format, use the `lualatex` or `xelatex` engines with the `fontspec` package.  Search this site for `fontspec` and you’ll find many explanations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change default font to Rockwell?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43591/how-to-change-default-font-to-rockwell)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: the marked duplicate hardly ever helps for a beginner.

Comment: Check out the [wiki book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Using_arbitrary_system_fonts).